# Returning values at program exit

Tags: c#, windows

I am aware that you can pass parameters into a program's execution.

i.e.:

```
myprogram.exe param1 param2 [...]
```

But if I wanted to retrieve several values on program exit (say I wanted to echo param1 and param2 back to the calling process), the only way I know of doing so would be to use an exit code (which would be impractical with larger/multiple parameters), or passing them via a temporary file.

Is there anything analogous to retrieving multiple values on a program's exit, much like how you can pass multiple arguments on a program's start?

Comment: @Kevin: You can't directly pass anything other than an exit code out of a program without using some additional mechanism.

Comment: Didn't realize he was talking about a console project, I should've looked closer at his example before commenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix systems, it is common to implement a complex task by piping the output of one program to the input of the next.

You would write the output from your first program to stdout (e.g. using Console.WriteLine), and the next program would then read from stdin to get the data it needs to further process the work.

That can very well be done in a .NET/Windows environment as well.

Having said that, it may be more desirable to use a more modern means of passing state from one program to the next. You can write state for example in a database that both have access to, or you can use a message queue to pass information along.

You can even pass information between two programs while they are still running with a mechanism such as named pipe.

You could also move the functionality from several programs into a library (DLL), if you have control of all of the code, and write a new program that orchestrates the entire process making use of that library.

You have many options. The best solution depends on what you want to achieve.